# How to restore RAID1 configuration with 2 different HardDrives in CentOS-7

Tags: linux, centos, raid, hard-drive, raid1

We have a server **(HP ProLiant ML10 Gen 9)** that came with Two Identical Hard disks. It was assumed that the server supports hardware RAID 1 (Mirror), and the **CentOS-7** was installed in it. But later we got to know that the server doesn't support Hardware RAID1 and also the software RAID1 was not configured properly.

[***lsblk*** output shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnn0k.png)

```
[root@himalaya ~]# lsblk
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                      8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
└─md126                  9:126  0  1.8T  0 raid1
  ├─md126p1            259:0    0  200M  0 md
  ├─md126p2            259:1    0    1G  0 md
  └─md126p3            259:2    0  1.8T  0 md
    ├─cl_himalaya-root 253:0    0   50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─cl_himalaya-swap 253:1    0  7.8G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─cl_himalaya-home 253:2    0  1.8T  0 lvm   /home
sdb                      8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
├─sdb1                   8:17   0  200M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sdb2                   8:18   0    1G  0 part  /boot
└─sdb3                   8:19   0  1.8T  0 part
sr0                     11:0    1  4.1G  0 rom
```

[***cat /proc/mdstat*** output shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFHNH.png)

```
[root@himalaya ~]# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1]
md126 : active raid1 sda[0]
      1953511424 blocks super external:/md127/0 [2/1] [U_]

md127 : inactive sda[0](S)
      3160 blocks super external:imsm

unused devices: <none>
```

As you can see in the above pictures the boot partition is in drive **sdb** whereas the root (/) partition and other files are in the drive **sda**.
Unfortunately the harddisk partitions are not identical.  Now I want to create a **software RAID1** without deleting my content from drive **sda**. So I kindly request someone to help me on how to move the boot partition from the drive **sdb** to drive **sda**. *(the drive **sdb** can be formatted after moving the boot partitions to sda).* and then how to create identical partitions and configure **RAID1** Array.

Please Note: That Drive **sdb** seems to be failed/failing. And the /boot partition is located in this drive **sdb**. But before replacing the harddisk I want to find a way to fix this.

```
    [root@himalaya ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907022847  1953511423+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907022847  1953511423+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental ph                                                                                                             ase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/md126: 2000.4 GB, 2000395698176 bytes, 3907022848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4C553ADE-504A-495C-9195-7B11C068ED27


#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      2508799      1G  Microsoft basic
 3      2508800   3907020799    1.8T  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/cl_himalaya-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl_himalaya-swap: 8321 MB, 8321499136 bytes, 16252928 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/cl_himalaya-home: 1937.1 GB, 1937093165056 bytes, 3783385088 se                                                                                                             ctors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: UEFI cannot boot from not FAT partitions. Show output of `fdisk -l`. If you have the 2048 bytes gap, you can use the MBR boot. Otherwise you need two-step operation, that will be described if required.

Comment: Hi Anton, please find the above post edited with the output of `fdisk -l`.